# What happen if I delete App.config in C# application?

Tags: c#, app-config, delete-file

I write a small application, that I don't need store anything in config files. So the file `App.config` in my source is exactly what ever Visual Studio has created.
So I want to delete this file from source code (before compiling). But I noticed that it also contains the .NET version information. I wonder if I delete `App.config` file, then copy my application to other pc, is it have any strange behavior?

Comment: Why not consider it part of your source code? You wouldn't delete your .cs files, would you?

Comment: @Andrew: that is a common WPF app. I just curious what happen.

Comment: @ThiefMaster If that it source code, why it sits in bin folder? I don't have any .cs files in program output.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> I wonder if I delete App.config file, then copy my application to other pc, is it have any strange behavior?

Nope, it should be fine. There are various (somewhat tortuous) rules about exactly what version of the CLR etc gets used in what situations, but for the most part you're fine to just rely on the default behaviour.

You really don't need an `app.config` file unless you need to give specific settings.

Comment: Thank you! If I delete it from source code (before complie), does it will fine, too?

Comment: @TuyenTk: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: Then, if my app use .NET 4 and I copy my app to a win7 pc doesn't have it yet. Can this pc recognize it lack .NET 4?

Comment: @TuyenTk: It will fail to start, but it would fail to start anyway if you require .NET 4.

Comment: I tried copy a .NET 4 app to a win7 pc with only .NET 3.5. If I dont delete App.config, it show dialog suggest me install .NET 4, but if I delete App.config from source code, it show a error dialog tell me it can't run the app. Does Windows is always acts like this?

Comment: @TuyenTk: Quite possibly - but how much of an issue is this for you? Do you even need the features of .NET 4, or could you target .NET 3.5 instead? Who is the app targeted at? If you're building an installer for it, that should install the relevant version anyway...