# Change output of Visual Studio Application (app.config not in root directory)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, app-config

I have developed an application, which has an assembly ( .dll ) which I would like to locate under a /bin directory, and not in the root directory itself. So I changed the app.config, that it also looks into sub folders, this works fine.

But with this change I have a .exe.config file in the root directory, is it possible to move this file also, or is this impossible?

I would like to have only the .exe in the root folder, and some directories, but no other files.

Thank you
Regards

Comment: well the best option would be just to keep a shortcut of the .exe in the root folder because u see, u an exe depends on assemblies(.dlls). But i guess u can move the `.exe.config.`...Give it a try or just go with a shourtcut

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I can't just move the .exe.config to the /bin folder, because then it isn't lookinf after the .dll in the subfolders.
I also can't use shortcuts, or I don't want to ;). I would like to distribute this application also like a "portable version" and so it's not possible to use shortcuts :/. any other ideas?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860308/what-happen-if-i-delete-app-config-in-c-sharp-application) might help

Comment: I know that I don't need the app.config, in case I don't make any changes to this file, but as I need to have a .dll in a subfolder, not in de root directory, I need the app.config to tell the .exe to also have a look at certain sub folders for the .dlls, so I can't just delete this :/

Comment: Hey wait,,, why don't you just embed the .dll in your .exe ..?? [follow this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025127/how-to-embed-dll-from-class-project-into-my-project-in-vb-net) and for god's sake, from next time on , be a bit more clear bruh...