# How can i hide configuration files for a c# .exe?

Tags: c#, windows, configuration, exe, archive

I have an app that needs a json file in the same directory, but the file is directly visible and accessible when anyone uses it,and editing it could break my app. How can i hide that file? Im looking for an archive or packaging method thay would still let me execute the exe.

Edit: A single file solution would be ideal, maybe an archive that executes my exe and stores the other file?

Comment: When you ship that config-file there´s not much you can do, in fact a config-file is for - guess what? - configuring your app. You may encode the file in some way, however...

Comment: @HimBromBeere You are right, however i have an app made just for generating that config file and i would like to ship a single file instead of a compressed archive

Answer (score 2):

You can try hiding the file by using [File.SetAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.setattributes?view=netcore-3.1):

```
File.SetAttributes(path, File.GetAttributes(path) | FileAttributes.Hidden);
```

Comment: Thanks, that is soemthing ill look into but im looking for more of a single-file way to do that. I would still have to compress the files to ship them. That does however solve my first problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your aplication is *very* small and doesn't use certain frameworks you can delete the app.config file altogether.

See answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20860326/8252265)

If you have a few variables in your config, you'll now have to make static class to define them at compile time.

```
class MySettings{
    public const string Setting1="Value of setting 1";
    public const string Setting2="Value of setting 2";
}
```

And in your code:

```
var setting = MySettings.Setting1;//then use your setting in your code
```

The idea of having a config file is so that you can make changes *after* the application has been deployed. For complex apps, you may have a different config file for each deployment environment (e.g. develeopment environment, test environment, live environment, etc)

Comment: I meant my own custom config file ^^. I created it specifically for what you said - so i could change values without rebuilding the entire app. I think ill use @JeremyRock 's answer, but thank you!